# How to send data from website to popup with executeScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Im getting data from website properly but how to send it to popup.js? I tried executeScript's callback but it doesnt work for me.

popup.js

```
function getData() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true},function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id,{
            file: 'getdata.js'
        });
    });
}
document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', getData);

 function loadData() {
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
              chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {url: tabs[0].url});
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id,{
                    file: 'loaddata.js'
              });
             });
          }

document.getElementById('clickme2').addEventListener('click', loadData);
```

getdata.js

```
var div = document.querySelectorAll('div');
var array = [];
div.forEach(function(item) {
    item.getAttribute('data');
    array.push(item.getAttribute('data'));
});
console.log(array);
```

loaddata.js

```
         var div = document.querySelectorAll('div');
              div.forEach(function(item, i){
                            item.setAttribute('data', array[i]);
                        });
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "aa",
    "description": "bb",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
        "48": "icon.png"
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>", "contentSettings", "contextMenus", "unlimitedStorage"],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "popup.js"]
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
1. Getting data works with executeScript after adding array; at the end of getdata.js.

2. How to send an array; from popup.js/getdata.js to loaddata.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript),

> "The result of the script is the last evaluated statement"

So, use the callback of `executeScript`, but instead of using `console.log(array)` in your getdata.js, try adding just a single line:

```
array;
```

as the very last line.

Comment: Thanks! It works, i can see the array values in my console log in popup.js. But i have another problem, i must send from those array; from popup.js to my loaddata.js(I have added loadData() and loaddata.js to my question)

Comment: You can store the array in a variable in background.js when you get the callback from getdata.js. Then when you insert loaddata.js, have that script do a chrome.runtime.sendMessage to your extension. Check it out in the documentation. In the background script, set up a listener for messages and when you receive the message from your loaddata, just return the array variable. Does that make sense?

Comment: At some point makes, but i dont know where to start. It is my first extension, i only now same basic stuff like chrome.tabs etc. Could you explain it to me all of this step by step?

Comment: First: Did you get the array back in your callback? Can you store it in a variable in your background script?

Comment: Cool, now you need to set up a listener for messages in your background script. Using chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function callback). You can read the documentation for it here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime

Comment: After that you need to set up a chrome.runtime.sendMessage from your loaddata.js, so that the onMessage listener can receive that message and send back the array variable.

Comment: I give up on that, i totally redesign logic of my popup.js. Now I'm sending array to from getData() to localstorage. I can see it in console.log at popup.js. How i can now just access that value from localStorage.getItem('ARRAY') in loaddata.js? It shows just null.

Comment: I'm not sure that would work the way you intend it to, unless you only want it to work on a single website. Data that you put into localStorage on a website is only available to fetch again from localStorage if you are on that same website. I guess you would achieve that in the best way using chrome.storage. Check out the documentation here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: Btw, if my answer did solve the issue you were having in your original post - please consider marking my answer as correct for others who may come across this thread :)